# How to write to file in Repeat loop in R

Tags: r

I have six files containing 6 million entries in a space delimited ascii file.  I am using the maptools package to read in the ascii file (read.ascii).  Each file represents a pixel in an image.  I need to sum over each individual pixel entity (data point 1 in table 1 + data point 1 table 2 + .... + data point 1 table 6).  I have created a program that can pull and sum the i-th pixel in the image.  I am however, having issues figuring out how to write these summations to one ascii file.  Any Ideas?

### My code:

```
library(maptools)

#Variable Declaration
num <- 6210775
i <- 1
#Open the 6 Factor files
tablex <- data.frame(readAsciiGrid("E:/KOC/Satellite/Daytime/PCA_R_CART/PSPP_PCA_01.asc"))
tabley <- data.frame(readAsciiGrid("E:/KOC/Satellite/Daytime/PCA_R_CART/PSPP_PCA_02.asc"))
tablez <- data.frame(readAsciiGrid("E:/KOC/Satellite/Daytime/PCA_R_CART/PSPP_PCA_03.asc"))
tablea <- data.frame(readAsciiGrid("E:/KOC/Satellite/Daytime/PCA_R_CART/PSPP_PCA_04.asc"))
tableb <- data.frame(readAsciiGrid("E:/KOC/Satellite/Daytime/PCA_R_CART/PSPP_PCA_05.asc"))
tabled <- data.frame(readAsciiGrid("E:/KOC/Satellite/Daytime/PCA_R_CART/PSPP_PCA_06.asc"))

repeat{
#Variable declaration for position within data frame
x <- tablex[i,1]

y <- tabley[i,1]

z <- tablez[i,1]

a <- tablea[i,1]

b <- tableb[i,1]

d <- tabled[i,1]

#Adding up ALL six factors
ALL <- x+y+z+a+b+d
#Write to file--This is my issue...
print(ALL)
#Iterative variable
i=i+1
#Condition to break if i is GT the number of preset lines
if(i > num){
  break
 }
}
```

Comment: Print doesn't write. Look up ?write.table

Comment: If you're going to write multiple times to the same file, you'll want to use the `append=TRUE` argument inside `write.table`, so that it won't overwrite all your previous data each time you write additional data to the file.

Comment: Oliver Keyes I realize print doesnt write, i was using that as a check to see if the values in ALL were actually there, but thanks for the direction with the write.table.

Comment: @eipi10 Thanks! I was not using the append=TRUE in my write statement (not included in example above).  I will try the code you posted below.  Looks much simpler.  I am still new at writing in R, so any shortcuts and clean up greatly help my self-education process!  I will try out the code soon.

Comment: Okay. Let me know if you need explanations of anything in my answer or if you get any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, as you haven't provided sample data, but I think you can simplify and shorten your code considerably. In this version, you get rid of the repeat loop, do all the sums first, and then write to a file only once.

```
# Read the 6 factor files and store them in a list
tables = lapply(1:6, function(x) {
  readAsciiGrid(paste0("E:/KOC/Satellite/Daytime/PCA_R_CART/PSPP_PCA_0", x, ".asc"))
})

# Instead of hard-coding num, you can also do, for example: num=nrow(tables[[1]])
num = 6210775

# Function to sum one set of values
oneSum = function(row) {
    sum(sapply(1:length(tables), function(x) {
          tables[[x]][row,1]
    }))
 }

# Run the oneSum function on every row of the ascii grids and store the results
# in allSums
allSums = sapply(1:num, oneSum)

# Write the data to a file
write.table(allSums, file="output.file.txt")
```

**UPDATE:** I changed the code to use `sapply` instead of `lapply`, which simplifies things a bit.